# CSS - All tiles not shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to develop a gallery wherin mouse hover shows an image that can be clicked to open. I got everything to work but once I added the links, things got a bit messy. Not It is only showing the last tile. Heres the code for your reference:

HTML:

```
    <div id="gallery">

    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/6.jpg" />
    </div></a>

    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/10.jpg" />
    </div></a>
    
    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/21.jpg" />
    </div></a>
    
    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/22.jpg" />
    </div></a>
    
    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/23.jpg" />
    </div></a>
    
    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/28.jpg" />
    </div></a>
    
    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/34.jpg" />
    </div></a>
    
    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/35.jpg" />
    </div></a>
    
    <a href="#"><div class="tile">
      <img src="pictures/84.jpg" />
    </div></a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    height: 100vh;  
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #gallery {
    height: 140vmax;
    width: 140vmax;  
    position: absolute;
  }

  .tile {
    border-radius: 1vmax;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 800ms ease;
  }
  
  .tile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  
.tile:hover > img {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.01);
  }

  
.tile > img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease,
      transform 800ms ease;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: rgb(255, 238, 88);
    height: 14%;
    width: 20%;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: rgb(66, 165, 245);
    height: 24%;
    width: 14%;
    left: 42%;
    top: 12%;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: rgb(239, 83, 80);
    height: 18%;
    width: 16%;
    left: 12%;
    top: 34%;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: rgb(102, 187, 106);
    height: 14%;
    width: 12%;
    left: 45%;
    top: 48%;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: rgb(171, 71, 188);
    height: 16%;
    width: 32%;
    left: 8%;
    top: 70%;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: rgb(255, 167, 38);
    height: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    left: 68%;
    top: 8%;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: rgb(63, 81, 181);
    height: 16%;
    width: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 74%;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(8) {
    background-color: rgb(141, 110, 99);
    height: 24%;
    width: 18%;
    left: 72%;
    top: 42%;
  }
  
  .tile:nth-child(9) {
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    height: 10%;
    width: 8%;
    left: 84%;
    top: 84%;
  }
  
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

const gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");

window.onmousemove = e => {
  const mouseX = e.clientX,
        mouseY = e.clientY;
  
  const xDecimal = mouseX / window.innerWidth,
        yDecimal = mouseY / window.innerHeight;
  
  const maxX = gallery.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth,
        maxY = gallery.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;
  
  const panX = maxX * xDecimal * -1,
        panY = maxY * yDecimal * -1;
  
  gallery.animate({
    transform: `translate(${panX}px, ${panY}px)`
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    fill: "forwards",
    easing: "ease"
  })
}

});
```

I need all the tile to show at their respective places and **if you want to see how it should actually look, you can just remove all the link tags.**

*It would also be helpful if someone can tell me how I can automate adding new images using an algorithm instead of 'nth child'.*

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `<a></div></a>` doesn't rings any bells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the CSS, in particular the `nth-child` selector. This selector is counting children of the parent element `#gallery`, but with your HTML structure where every `.tile` is wrapped with an `<a>` tag, every `.tile` is actually the first and only child of its parent `<a>` tag.

A better approach would be to apply the `.tile` class to the `<a>` tag itself, which would allow the CSS to apply to every individual link as a direct child of `#gallery`.

In the CSS, you could keep using `nth-child()` for simplicity, or if you want to have more control, you could also generate classes dynamically (like `tile-1`, `tile-2`, etc.) and define styles for those classes.

If you have hundreds of images that you would like to load a JavaScript code similar to this will solve your problem:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");

  for(let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
    const tile = document.createElement("a");
    tile.href = "#";
    tile.classList.add("tile");

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = `pictures/${i}.jpg`;
    
    tile.appendChild(img);
    gallery.appendChild(tile);
  }
};
```

I have to point out that this code assumes that .jpg files under the pictures folder is named as 1.jpg, 2.jpg... and so on. If you have a different naming convention, you should alter the `img.src=...` line accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! this works. 
But do you have any suggestions on how I can scale adding new images? 
I don't wanna be stuck doing this for every image. I have more than a hundred images!!!

Comment: In that case need to automate the process by adding new images dynamically using JavaScript.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The HTML is not the issue. Problem lies with CSS.

I want the images to be placed in random sizes in seemingly random positions that look aesthetically pleasing.

I want to know if there exists some algorithm that can do this for me. (position and sizing).

and yes, the naming convention is as you said!

Comment: Add the styles through JavaScript. Generate random numbers and add them through `element.style.height = randomHeight;` etc. Anything that you want to put logic into will be done by JavaScript, so think about ways you can accomplish them through that. In this case, just add common CSS properties through classes and add everything else on the specific element as if you are adding the element to the HTML file as `<div styles="..."></div>`, which is accomplished by properties like `styles.size`.